# Taking the mean of a multitude of variables that will grouped by a set of categorcal variables

Tags: r

I have 500 columns. One is a categorical variable with 3 categories and the rest are continuous variables. There are 50 rows that fall under these columns. How do I group the data frame by the categorical variables, and take the mean of the observations that fall within each category for every column that has continuous variables for that DF? ALSO, remove all NA. I want to create a new CD from this info.

Best,
Henry

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I would recommend these (guidelines)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example] to maximize your chances of getting help. Try to provide some data and some code to illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting to SO, please ensure to include a reproducible example of your data (`dput` is helpful for this). As it is, I can only guess to the structure of your data.

I like doing general grouping/summarising operations with `dplyr`. Using `iris` as an example, you might be able to do somehting like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data(iris)

iris %>% 
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(mean)
```

`summarise_all` just automatically uses all non-grouping columns, and takes a function you want to apply.

Note, if you use the dev version of dplyr, you could also do something like

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(is.numeric), mean)
```

Since `summarise_all` is being replaced in favor of `across`